# installing pandas in pydev eclipse neon 2

Tags: eclipse, python-3.x, pandas, pydev

I have installed python 3.6.4 on my MAC OS and have Eclipse neon 2.0 running. I have added pydev plugin to work on python projects. I need to import pandas library, but there is no such option as windows -> preferences -> libraries

Can someone help me with any other way to install python libraries in neon 2.

And also how to run python cmds in terminal window in pydev?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The best way to install something would be doing a `pip install pandas`. You can do this in the command line or in `preferences > pydev > interpreters > python interpreter > install/uninstall with pip` (button).

To use the interactive console in PyDev, follow the steps on: http://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_interactive_console.html

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem when working with `eclipse` pydev project.
here are `steps` that helped me resolve the issue

1. In eclipse open the workspace, click on Windows->Preferences->pydev-> interpreters-> python interpreter -> Click on Manage with PIP
2. In Command to execute , enter install pandas.

**Problem solved**